# How to spy/mock method calls in the constructor of a Angular 5 service?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular5

I have a service, that makes 2 method calls in the constructor:

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiURL = environment.apiURL;
    this.method();
    this.method2().subscribe();
  }
```

I'm trying to test this service in the TestBed. However, I am unable to spyOn, using Jasmine's spies, before the `TestBed.get(MyService)`.

Here's my Service's TestBed configuration:

```
  let myService: MyService;
  let backend: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MyService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
    backend = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
```

How do I properly spyOn `method()` and `method2()` and return a value for them. Is putting methods in the constructor if a Service not a good practice?

`method()` and `method2()` sends a http call to the server to "refresh" the data that the user might need, eg `Posts` on a wall. Another method is an `Observable.timer` that gets set to the age of the token, to auto sign out the app once expiration of the token is met.

Comment: *Is putting methods in the constructor if a Service not a good practice?* - this totally depends on what are these methods and how they work. They don't present in the code above.

Comment: @estus, they are method calls that starts the auto timeout, via an Observable.timer, based on a jwt's expiration time. As well as to fetch some data that the user would like to see, eg `Posts` on their wall or something.

Answer (score 1):

If `method` and `method2` are prototype methods, they can be spied on class prototype:

```
it('', () => {
  spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'method').and.callThrough();
  spyOn(MyService.prototype, 'method2').and.callThrough();
  const svc = TestBed.get(MyService);
  expect(svc['method']).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(svc['method2']).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It always depends on the methods if they are appropriate for use in constructor.

If a methods returns a subscription, it should be saved as a property, because it may be unsubscribe later, for example on service destruction.

Considering that `method` and `method2` are asynchronous, this may be an antipattern. If they trigger requests that are expected to be completed on service instantiation, this will result in race condition because they are not completed, and the service also doesn't expose a promise or an observable to track the status of requests. The proper solution would be to not call them in constructor but at some place that is appropriate for asynchronous provider initialization, i.e. `APP_INITIALIZER` or route resolver.